# How to derive a state monad from first principles?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am trying to come up with an implementation of State Monad derived from examples of function composition. Here I what I came up with:

First deriving the concept of Monad:

```
data Maybe' a = Nothing' | Just' a deriving Show

sqrt' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
sqrt' x = if x < 0 then Nothing' else Just' (sqrt x)

inv' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
inv' x = if x == 0 then Nothing' else Just' (1/x)

log' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
log' x = if x == 0 then Nothing' else Just' (log x)
```

We can have function that composes these functions as follows:

```
sqrtInvLog' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
sqrtInvLog' x = case (sqrt' x) of
                  Nothing' -> Nothing'
                  (Just' y) -> case (inv' y) of
                                Nothing' -> Nothing'
                                (Just' z) -> log' z
```

This could be simplified by factoring out the case statement and function application:

```
fMaybe' :: (Maybe' a) -> (a -> Maybe' b) -> Maybe' b
fMaybe' Nothing' _ = Nothing'
fMaybe' (Just' x) f = f x

-- Applying fMaybe' =>
sqrtInvLog'' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
sqrtInvLog'' x = (sqrt' x) `fMaybe'` (inv') `fMaybe'` (log')`
```

Now we can generalize the concept to any type, instead of just Maybe' by defining a Monad =>

```
class Monad' m where
  bind' :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  return' :: a -> m a

instance Monad' Maybe' where
  bind' Nothing' _ = Nothing'
  bind' (Just' x) f = f x
  return' x = Just' x
```

Using Monad' implementation, sqrtInvLog'' can be written as:

```
sqrtInvLog''' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe' a
sqrtInvLog''' x = (sqrt' x) \bind'` (inv') `bind'` (log')`
```

Trying to apply the concept to maintain state, I defined something as shown below:

```
data St a s = St (a,s) deriving Show

sqrtLogInvSt' :: (Floating a, Ord a) => St a a -> St (Maybe' a) a
sqrtLogInvSt' (St (x,s)) = case (sqrt' x) of
                             Nothing' -> St (Nothing', s)
                             (Just' y) -> case (log' y) of
                                            Nothing' -> St (Nothing', s+y)
                                            (Just' z) -> St (inv' z, s+y+z)
```

It is not possible to define a monad using the above definition as bind needs to be defined as taking in a single type "m a".

Second attempt based on Haskell's definition of State Monad:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

First attempt to define function that is built using composed functions and maintains state:

```
fex1 :: Int->State Int Int
fex1 x = State { runState = \s->(r,(s+r)) } where r = x `mod` 2`

fex2 :: Int->State Int Int
fex2 x = State { runState = \s-> (r,s+r)} where r = x * 5
```

A composed function:

```
fex3 x = (runState (fex2 y)) st where (st, y) = (runState (fex1 x)) 0
```

But the definition `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }` does not fit the pattern of `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` of bind

An attempt could be made as follows:

```
instance Monad' (State s) where
   bind' st f = undefined
   return' x = State { runState = \s -> (x,s) }
```

bind' is undefined above becuase I did not know how I would implement it.

I could derive why monads are useful and apply it the first example (Maybe') but cannot seem to apply it to State. It will be useful to understand how I could derive the State Moand using concepts defined above.

Note that I have asked a similar question earlier: [Haskell - Unable to define a State monad like function using a Monad like definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205421/haskell-unable-to-define-a-state-monad-like-function-using-a-monad-like-defini) but I have expanded here and added more details.

Comment: Your `return` is incorrect too as `a` is not defined. Perhaps fixing it would provide a hint re. `bind`.

Comment: thanks, that was a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate the hint in an answer

Comment: Calling your type `ST` is [slightly confusing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html).

Comment: There is only one sensible way to define `bind`. Follow the types. You have two functions (one is wrapped in State but that's not essential). You need to return a function (again wrapped, but it doesn't matter). So you start to write that function. `\s -> ...` Ok now you have an `s`, what can you do with it *and* the two functions you already have? Follow the types!

Comment: @n.m. is my approach of partial type (State s) right? That was the only thing I could think of. Not sure if it is right though.

Comment: Looks ok to me but you want to define bind to be sure. If you can, then it's correct.

Comment: It is sort of partial type, because the type State needs two 's' and 'a', but I have kind of defined a partial type (State s). I dont know enough about this

Comment: @n.m. There's [more than one sensible way to define `bind`](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/08/10/mindfuck-the-reverse-state-monad/); and following the types is not enough to prevent bugs: even in the standard implementation of `bind` there are multiple values of type `s` floating around at the point where you have to return a `(b,s)`, so it is easy to put the wrong one and have a buggy but type-correct implementation.

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed there are two things of type `s`, one that you've got as an input and one you compute with the left operand of `bind`. Yes you need to be equipped with some common sense to return the correct one. Or enable warnings and get a message about an unused local bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your composed function `fex3` has the wrong type:

```
fex3 :: Int -> (Int, Int)
```

Unlike with your `sqrtInvLog'` example for `Maybe`', `State` does not appear in the type of `fex3`.

We could define it as

```
fex3 :: Int -> State Int Int
fex3 x = State { runState = \s ->
    let (y, st) = runState (fex1 x) s in
        runState (fex2 y) st }
```

The main difference to your definition is that instead of hardcoding `0` as the initial state, we pass on our own state `s`.

What if (like in your `Maybe` example) we wanted to compose three functions? Here I'll just reuse `fex2` instead of introducing another intermediate function:

```
fex4 :: Int -> State Int Int
fex4 x = State { runState = \s ->
        let (y, st) = runState (fex1 x) s in
            let (z, st') = runState (fex2 y) st in
                runState (fex2 z) st' }
```

---

***SPOILERS:***

The generalized version `bindState` can be extracted as follows:

```
bindState m f = State { runState = \s ->
    let (x, st) = runState m s in
    runState (f x) st }

fex3' x = fex1 x `bindState` fex2
fex4' x = fex1 x `bindState` fex2 `bindState` fex2
```

---

We can also start with `Monad'` and types.

The `m` in the definition of `Monad'` is applied to one type argument (`m a`, `m b`). We can't set `m = State` because `State` requires two arguments. On the other hand, partial application is perfectly valid for types: `State s a` really means `(State s) a`, so we can set `m = State s`:

```
instance Monad' (State s) where
   -- return' :: a -> m a (where m = State s)
   -- return' :: a -> State s a
   return' x = State { runState = \s -> (x,s) }

   -- bind' :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b (where m = State s)
   -- bind' :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
   bind' st f =
   -- Good so far: we have two arguments
   --   st :: State s a
   --   f :: a -> State s b
   -- We also need a result
   --   ... :: State s b
   -- It must be a State, so we can start with:
       State { runState = \s ->
   -- Now we also have
   --   s :: s
   -- That means we can run st:
           let (x, s') = runState st s in
   --   runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)
   --   st :: State s a
   --   s :: s
   --   x :: a
   --   s' :: s
   -- Now we have a value of type 'a' that we can pass to f:
   --   f x :: State s b
   -- We are already in a State { ... } context, so we need
   -- to return a (value, state) tuple. We can get that from
   -- 'State s b' by using runState again:
           runState (f x) s'
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-state-monad). Summing and extending a bit.

If you have a function

```
ta -> tb
```

and want to add "state" to it, then you should pass that state along, and have

```
(ta, ts) -> (tb, ts)
```

You can transform this by currying it:

```
ta -> ts -> (tb, ts)
```

If you compare this with the original `ta -> tb`, we obtain (adding parentheses)

```
ta -> (ts -> (tb, ts))
```

**Summing up, if a function returns `tb` from `ta` (i.e. `ta -> tb`), a "stateful"
version of it will return (`ts -> (tb, ts)`) from `ta` (i.e. `ta -> (ts -> (tb, ts))`)**

**Therefore, a "stateful computation" (just one function, or either a chain of functions dealing with state) must return/produce this:**

```
(ts -> (tb, ts))
```

This is the typical case of a stack of ints.
`[Int]` is the State

```
pop :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int]) -- remove top
pop (v:s) -> (v, s)

push :: Int -> [Int] -> (int, [Int]) -- add to the top
push v s -> (v, v:s)
```

For `push`, the type of `push 5` is the same than type of `pop :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])`.
So we would like to combine/join this basic operations to get things as

```
duplicateTop =
   v <- pop
   push v
   push v
```

Note that, as desired, `duplicateTop :: [Int] -> (Int, [Int])`

**Now: how to combine two stateful computations to get a new one?**
Let's do it (Caution: this definition is not the same that the
used for the `bind` of monad (`>>=`) but it is equivalent).

Combine:

```
f :: ta -> (ts -> (tb, ts))
```

with

```
g :: tb -> (ts -> (tc, ts))
```

to get

```
h :: ta -> (ts -> (tc, ts))
```

This is the construction of h (in pseudo-haskell)

```
h = \a -> ( \s -> (c, s') )
```

where we have to calculate `(c, s')` (the rest in the expressions are just parameters `a` and `s`). Here it is how:

```
                   -- 1. run f using a and s
  l1 = f a         -- use the parameter a to get the function (ts -> (tb, ts)) returned by f 
  (b, s1) = l1 s   -- use the parameter s to get the pair that l1 returns ( :: (tb, ts) )
                   -- 2. run g using f output, b and s1
  l2  = g b        -- use b to get the function (ts -> (tb, ts)) returned by g
  (c, s') = l2 s1  -- use s1 to get the pair that l2 returns ( :: (tc, ts) )
```